# Put the selected text in a variable of my application

Tags: c#, wpf, string, selected

In my application, I have a `textbox`. I want to be able to copy text from a webpage or document open elsewhere in Windows by simply highlighting the text and pressing a global hotkey - then have that text appear in the `textbox`.

What I am stuck on is the selection part: I'm looking for a way to use the selected text as  a variable within my WPF application, but I can't seem to get access to it in a way that makes sense.

Right now, I'm working with the clipboard and `Clipboard.GetText()` to get my variable :

```
private void OnHotKeyHandler(HotKey hotKey) {
    if (Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Text))
        tb_number.Text = Clipboard.GetText();
}
```

But i'm trying to avoid a tedious `CTRL-C` each time i want to get this value and work with selected text, rather than copied text. Any ideas how I can do this `on-select` rather than by accessing the clipboard?

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO. When asking questions, it's best to tell us what you've tried and researched so far, and be specific about the problem you're having. Note that you can edit your question at any time to add additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive the question is much clearer now. Thanks for the editing.

I dont think you can modify the clipboard functionality thru a .NET application in an easy way. But you may get what you need with a third party application for windows called autohotkey.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Send

https://superuser.com/questions/166270/change-ctrl-x-c-and-v-hotkeys-in-windows-to-different-keys